# How to remove an item that contains a map that I build with a ListView.builder using a button (a cart page) ? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a cart page in my app that contains a list of items.
I build this list with a ListView.builder. The content it returns contains a data from API.
Here's the visual of it
[image: cart with 2 items]
[image: cart with 3 items]

and here's my code

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cartController.cartList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery
                        .of(context)
                        .size
                        .width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffF1F5F9),
                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Color(0xff7D7D7D).withOpacity(0.6),
                            blurRadius: 4.0,
                            offset: Offset(2, 3))
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 6, 10, 6),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 40,
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    useOldImageOnUrlChange: false,
                                    imageUrl:
                                    '${cartController.cartList.values.toList() [index]
                                        .image}',
                                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                        Stack(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Image.asset(
                                              Constants.loading,
                                              height: 30,
                                              width: 30,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                        Image.asset(
                                          "assets/logo/carisayur_empty.png",
                                          height: 20,
                                          width: 20,
                                        ),
                                  )),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, top: 12),
                                child: Text(
                                  '${cartController.cartList.values.toList() [index]
                                      .name}',
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Color(0xff31708F),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              IconButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  cartController.cartList.remove(index);
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  color: Color(0xff31708F),
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Image.asset("assets/icons/cancel.png"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          thickness: 0.8,
                          color: Color(0xffE1E1E1),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 70,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Kemasan",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width / 2,
                              child: Text(
                                "Jumlah",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                "Harga",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 70,
                              child: Text(
                                '${cartController.cartList.values.toList() [index]
                                    .kemasan}',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Color(0xff7F8A8E)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width / 2,
                              child: Text(
                                "1",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: Color(0xff7F8A8E)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                  "${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(
                                      cartController.cartList.values.toList() [index]
                                          .price ?? 0)}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      color: Color(0xff000000))),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          thickness: 0.8,
                          color: Color(0xffE1E1E1),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 6, 18, 6),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5.0),
                                child: Image.asset("assets/icons/edit.png"),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Edit",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 5),
                                child:
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isTap = !isTap;
                                    });
                                    if (isTap == true) {
                                      favAlert(
                                        'Barang berhasil \n'
                                            'ditambahkan \n'
                                            'ke Favorit',
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      favAlert(
                                          'Favorit dihapus'
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                  // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35, top: 3),
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: isTap == false
                                        ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 14,)
                                        : Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red, size: 14,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Favorit",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                "Total",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                                child:
                                Text(
                                  "${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(
                                      cartController.cartList.values.toList() [index]
                                          .price ?? 0)}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Color(0xff31708F),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

if I print the `cartController.cartList` and `cartController.cartList.length`, it will print `I/flutter ( 5474): {2907: Instance of 'UpdateCartProductResponse', 2916: Instance of 'UpdateCartProductResponse', 2820: Instance of 'UpdateCartProductResponse'}` and `3`

my problem is I can't remove one of the item with an IconButton that I made there.
How can I remove an item?

Comment: I recommend that in the onclick action of the button you have the id that you want to delete after you delete, do a setState so that the list is updated

Comment: I just did that and it still does nothing.